# php firebase push notification ios : ERROR InvalidRegistration

Tags: php, ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
$url = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";
$token = "xxx"; 
$serverKey = 'xxx';

$title = "Title";
$body = "Body of the message";

$notification = array('title' =>$title , 'text' => $body, 'body' => $body, 'sound' => 'default', 'badge' => '1');
$arrayToSend = array('to' => $token, 'notification' => $notification,'priority'=>'high', 'data' => $notification, 'content_available' => true);

$json = json_encode($arrayToSend);
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json';
$headers[] = 'Authorization: key='. $serverKey;


$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

pre($response);

curl_close($ch);
```

I CAN'T SEND NOTIFICATION

{"multicast_id":2200169071930988341,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}

Answer (score 1):

This means that the `$token` value you pass in is not registered on the current Firebase project. There are many reasons why this could happen, including that the token as expired and is no longer valid.

The usual way to handle this response is to remove the outdated token from your database, so that you don't pass it in calls to the FCM API in the future.

Comment: As long as I see you giving the same answers to the same questions again and again, I will upvote them again and again 

Comment: We provided API controls with firebase. There is no error in the token. Notification is sent via firebase with the same token.

Answer (score 0):

We provided API controls with firebase. There is no error in the token. Notification is sent via firebase with the same token.